# Variable HTML template in Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to find an 'Enlivonic' way of defining a function that will perform a transformation on a parameterised html template.

In other words, how do I define something like a defsnippet that also takes the template as an argument?

I looked at at, snippet and transformation, but I'm a little lost in the macros :-(

Comment: FYI, there is an enlive google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/enlive-clj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a transformation, but want to feed it different templates, you could try:

```
(defn multi-template [t]
    (template t [h1 h2]
         [:h1] (content h1)
         [:h2] (content h2)))
```

This function, when called with an html template will return a function that takes h1 and h2 as arguments and substitutes them into the given template. Call it as follows:

```
((multi-template "your-template.html") "heading 1 content" "heading 2 content")
```

I used something similar to this when I had a number of different picture gallery designs as templates and wanted to switch between dynamically.

Note: this dynamically creates the template each time, whereas the `deftemplate` macro just calls template once at compile time. So if this is too slow, there are things you can do to optimise it (see [clojure, enlive, multi-site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772481/clojure-enlive-multi-site?rq=1))